# What may cause my fatal error Call to undefined function _menu_target_edit_form_extra_elements_submit()?

Tags: 7, media

I'm running Drupal 7.53 and all my modules are up to date. I suddenly started having this error on my Drupal site.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function _menu_target_edit_form_extra_elements_submit() in /home/portal/public_html/includes/form.inc on line 1520

This error happens when I try to add a new content type or edit a content type that includes a media or image field. It doesn't matter if the field is empty or contains content.  However, if I remove the field from the content type, it saves just fine.

Since my site is very event driven, I am unable to edit events until the problem is fixed.  I've run registry update, flushed caches, run cron...  you name it. I did not update any modules since it was working on Tuesday to when it stopped working this morning. I did update the media module on Tuesday but I am pretty sure I did this before I added a few events.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Hey I just had this issue this morning too. In my case it was being caused by the module **menu_target** I disabled it and the issue disappeared.

Comment: This solution worked for me, thank you! So far, disabling this module did not cause any noticeable harm.